# Using List of TemplateRef as ChildrenContent

Tags: angular

I wanna to create a component that gets a list of data and a list of templates in order to present each data using different template like this:

```
<my-component [data]="data">
    <ng-template let-name="prop" #format1>
            {{name}} As Format 1
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-name="prop" #format2>
            {{name}} As Format 2
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-name="prop" #format3>
            {{name}} As Format 3
    </ng-template>
</my-component>
```

It's OK when I pass only one `ng-template` to `my-component` and I can access it with:

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any>;
```

[Here is the working one](https://jsfiddle.net/6nLqgo3a/)

But as I want to pass many `ng-templates` to `my-component` and access templates using `@ContentChildren` as:

```
@ContentChildren(TemplateRef) templates: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;
```

[Here is the not working one](https://jsfiddle.net/eh0n1hwf/1/)

I get `this.templates` as `undefined`

I wanna to access passing `ng-templates` using `this.templates`

Comment: `I get this.templates as undefined` where did you get it? I don't see it in your example. Anyway, try `ngAfterContentInit` hook to access to `this.templates`. https://jsfiddle.net/tpmvy603/ As you can see all works as expected

Comment: based on @yurzui said, check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvrvm442/)

Comment: It's getting awkward. I have tested the first one inside `ngInit()` [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ovs3w8bx/) and I got the result. but when I want to use `@ContentChildren` there is no result in `ngInit()` : [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/t35u0xqg/). By the way, I think your answer will solve my problem